# What rim dimension is equivalent to “622x18”?

Tags: innertube

I have a puncture in my inner tube and need a new one. The dimensions indicated on both my old inner tube and my rim is 622x18. I don’t know what this means and the websites I am shopping on don’t present this as an option. [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  This is a common question, and a more generalized question (with answers) can be found at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/what-do-i-need-to-know-when-replacing-my-inner-tube-tires

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I need to know when replacing my inner tube/tires?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/what-do-i-need-to-know-when-replacing-my-inner-tube-tires)

Answer (score 3):

622 ISO is equal to a 700C wheel, 18 on the rim is the width probably internal width. So you would need a 700C tube. They usually have a range like 700C x 18-25 or something similar which is what you see on the tube. 29er wheels are also 622 ISO but generally wider.

You tire will also have a similar measurement on it for the size and width of the tire.